# Varying proportional size for 'bubble' Highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, image-resizing, label, bubble-chart

I have created a large bubble graph with Highcharts to show correlation between variables :
[image: Large View]

When I am zoomed out, I don't mind that we can't read the labels properly.
When I zoom in though, I would like that the bubble size and label sizes automatically adjust to the "new" screen size. Instead I have this :

[image: Small]

Any ideas to solve that issue ?
Cheers

Update : Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619012/change-datalabels-font-size-when-zooming-in-highcharts-bubble-graph)

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I got caught up in other projects and put this one on the backburner. I'll get back to it sometime this month though.

Comment: I asked the same question in a different way and got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619012/change-datalabels-font-size-when-zooming-in-highcharts-bubble-graph).