# Change dataLabels font size when zooming in Highcharts bubble graph

Tags: highcharts, label, zooming, bubble-chart

I originally created a graph using `highcharts` but I couldn't find a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862967/varying-proportional-size-for-bubble-highcharts-graph).
To summarize I show correlation between a big number of variables and for different time horizons. So for each couple of variable I have several bubbles whose diameter is proportional to the correlation value. The issue is that when I zoom in, the label size stays the same and is unreadable.

I wanted to implement somthing like this within the definition of my `chart`:

```
selection: function(event) {
    this.options.plotOptions.bubble.dataLabels.style.fontSize = somefunction();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any impact. All help welcome !

Comment: It's not possible to change plotOptions in real time. Instead for each series use: `series.update( newOptions );`

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks for the comment. That works but it is extremely slow. The graph takes more than one second to update after zooming in now. If you want to post it as an answer I'll validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PawelFus for the pointer.

Solution is to loop through all the series as it can't be done globally. It is extremely slow though : the bubble graph takes more than one second to update after I zoom in.

```
selection: function (event) {
            for (var s in this.series) {
                this.series[s].update({ 
                    dataLabels: {
                        style:{
                            fontSize: 11
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```